# how to make individual profile page?

Tags: codeigniter

i am new to the programming.i have list of customer in table.i want to make the individual profile page for each customer with their database credentials.So how can i do it to make name clickable so their profile page will open (in codeigniter).this is my table....

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">S/N</th>
            <th scope="col">Customer Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Customer Email</th>
            <th scope="col">Customer Country</th>
            <th scope="col">Customer City</th>
            <th scope="col">Customer Address</th>
            <th scope="col">Customer Contact</th>
            <th scope="col">Customer Image</th>
            <th scope="col">Modify</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <?php $i = 1;?>
        <?php if($customer->num_rows()>0):?>
        <?php foreach($customer->result() as $rows):?>

        <tr>

        <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php base_url();?>admin/customer/profile"<?php echo $rows->customer_name;?><a></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows->customer_email;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows->customer_country;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows->customer_city;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows->customer_address;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows->customer_contact;?></td>                              

        <td><img id="img" src="<?php echo base_url();?>customer/<?php echo $rows->customer_image;?>" width="30px" height="30px"/></td>                                      

        <td>

        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/customer/edit/<?php echo $rows->customer_id;?>" class="table-icon edit" title="Edit"></a>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/customer/delete/<?php echo $rows->customer_id;?>" class="table-icon delete" title="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure . You want to delete')"></a>

        </td>
        </tr>

        <?php $i++;?>

        <?php endforeach;?>

        <?php endif;?>


    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Paste Code Here....!
Each user have an id, send every user to the profile url with id so each user have different url.

Comment: how to submit id can you please...give me simple example

Comment: `<a href="<?php echo base_url().'profile/'.$id ?>" > Each User Profile </a>`

Comment: If you post the code here we can better explain you the solutions.